# Is the Yongnuo YN622C-TX still "working" when it's turned off?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, wireless-triggers, yongnuo

Today I used a Yongnuo YN622C-TX with a Canon 7D and spotted some strange behavior.
When the transmitter was on and I was shooting in A mode, the shutter speed was set to 1/250, as expected.

I turned off the transmitter, but the shutter speed was still 1/250, as if it was still powered on.

I repeated this several times, tried to reset the transmitter several times, but without any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing and replacing the batteries to reset the transmitter. Make sure the switch is in the off position when you reinsert the batteries. The transmitter should remain off. Then turn the transmitter on and see if the transmitter still stays on when turned back off. If it does then it sounds like the on/off switch is faulty. If you can you may want to return it for another copy. Unfortunately the price of shipping it to Asia for warranty service is probably more than the cost of buying another unit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried, still the same. When I turn off the trnasmiiter the LCD screen is turned on and I hear mechanical "click" of the switch. From this point of view this all looks fine, but camera still "sees" powered on flash :(